# Remove row for 2nd CSV if field in CSV 2 and CSV 1 has a field match

Tags: bash, csv, terminal

I have 2 CSVs and I that looks something like the following

### CSV 1

```
ID
001
002
```

### CSV 2

```
ID   Name   Optin   Date
001  Adam   TRUE    2020/01/01
002  Eve    TRUE    2019/11/01
003  John   FALSE   2019/07/22
```

I would like only the row with ID 003 in the output file, please. Because there are between 3-5 million rows, it'll have to be something in terminal and not excel.

Sorry the tables look so bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Request you to please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Also please do wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS to make them clear.

Comment: I have no idea how I would solve this. Just asking if there is a way to do this.

Comment: [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if (FNR>1) seen[$1]++; next} !seen[$1] {print}' csv1.txt csv2.txt
```

Lines broken for explanation:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
                        # this block is evaluated while reading csv1.txt only
        if (FNR > 1)    # skip the header line of csv1.txt
            seen[$1]++  # memorize the occurance of the ID
        next            # prevents from continuing to the next block
    }
                        # the lines below is evaluated while reading csv2.txt only
    ! seen[$1] {        # if the ID is not in the array (not included in csv1.txt)
        print           # then print the row
    }
' csv1.txt csv2.txt
```

- The condition `NR==FNR` is met only while reading the first file
  in the argument list (`csv1.txt` in this case).
  This is a common idiom to execute different codes for each file.
- The statement `seen[$1]++` sets a mark on the 1st field of the input line.
  You can easily know if the ID is included in `csv1.txt` while processing
  `csv2.txt`.